# Trouble with xlsx conversion using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a few .xlsx flat files I want to convert to csv.

This is what I have done

`Get-ChildItem  -Filter "Home*.xlsx" -Recurse | Get-Content | Add-Content "C:\Users\Pete\combined\Combined.csv"`

When I run this, it works but the file is not readable to any system, it seems to be all gibberish.

I am trying

`Get-ChildItem  -Filter "Home*.xlsx" -Recurse | Get-Content |ConvertTo-Csv | Add-Content "C:\Users\Pete\combined\Combined.csv"`

But no luck as well. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `Get-Content` is meant to read plain text files, what makes you believe `xlsx` is plain text ? You either need `Import-Excel` or COM object

Comment: If the Excel files are all the same (same columns) and single worksheets, it is a trivial thing to combine them all in one CSV using `Import-Excel`: `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx | Import-Excel | Export-Csv path/to/csv.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

- *Here is the PowerShell command to convert excel file to csv file*

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 5.4.2 
gci *.xlsx | %{Import-Excel $_ | Export-Csv ($_.basename + ".csv")}
```

- *Check this [Github document](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) regards with Import excel for complete information.*
  [image]
- *You can even use the script provided by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).*